# NET CORE 5. How to fix "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"?

Tags: c#, .net-core, runtime-error

This is my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>DockerDotNetWrapper</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>DockerDotNetWrapper.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Docker.DotNet" Version="3.125.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Docker.DotNet.BasicAuth" Version="3.125.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
      <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Unfortunately, I have message "Could not load file or assembly 'Docker.DotNet, Version=3.125.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)"

[image]

It seems DockerDotNetWrapper.dll.config with definition like this don't working in NET CORE 5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.6.0" newVersion="10.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

I see a number of trash file in \bin\Debug directory - DockerDotNetWrapper.deps.json, DockerDotNetWrapper.runtimeconfig.dev.json, DockerDotNetWrapper.runtimeconfig.json, project.assets.json \obj directory. But how to fix this issue in Net core 5.0?

Comment: Try deleting the "bin" and the "obj" folders and recompile

Comment: Thank you. @CristopherRosales, unfortunately so simple recipe don't working.

Answer (score 1):

My finally solution is simple rebuild my application from source code of this repository https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet (instead dumb nuget packages). In this way all working fine.
[image]

Comment: Maybe downgrading the version from the Nuget Package Manager would have worked too, but I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I try this way too before decide to use source code directly.